# Is there a way to use the new PostgreSQL 9.3 JSON operators in Phalcon?

Tags: php, phalcon, postgresql-9.3

I'm looking for a way to take advantage of the new [PostgreSQL JSON operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html) in [Phalcon Framework](http://phalconphp.com/en/).

A simple table to demonstrate:

```
CREATE TABLE "user"
(
  id_user serial NOT NULL,
  data json,
  CONSTRAINT pk_user PRIMARY KEY (id_user)
)
```

and a query which runs fine in `psql`:

```
select * from "user" where data->>'email' = 'john@example.com';
```

However when used against the [Phalcon model](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html):

```
$users = UserModel::query()
            ->where("data->>'email' = :email:")
            ->bind(['email' => 'john@example.com'])
            ->execute();
```

it produces syntax error:

```
ERROR: Syntax error, unexpected token >, near to '>'email' = :email:', when parsing: SELECT [Pht\Cli\Model\UserModel].* FROM [Pht\Cli\Model\UserModel] WHERE data->>'email' = :email:
```

I'm guessing that it has something to do with the [PHQL parser](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/phql.html) not being able to process the syntax. But the question remains: **how to use JSON query with Phalcon**?

I've tried to wrap the JSON syntax into a [Db\RawValue](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Db_RawValue.html):

```
$users = UserModel::query()
            ->where(new RawValue("data->>'email' = 'john@example.com'"))
            ->execute();
```

but it seems like it was made only for updating/inserting:

```
ERROR: Conditions must be string
```

I can always write a raw query, but that's obviously not the way to go. Also it would be nice to have the syntax available in `Model::find` and `Model::findAll`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of digging into the source code and reading the forums I found a quite good workaround based on [this forum post](http://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/1082/sneaking-in-subqueries-into-phql#C4020). The basic idea is to use custom database function syntax, catch and parse a special *virtual* function before executing the query:

```
UserModel::query()->where("PG_JSON_PATH(\"data->>'email'\") = :email:");
```

For this to work we need a specialized Postgres adapter (the one below also uses this hack to sneak in sub queries as in the original post):

```
class Postgresql93 extends \Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Postgresql
{
    public function query($sqlStatement, $bindParams = null, $bindTypes = null)
    {
        $sqlStatement = $this->handle93syntax($sqlStatement);
        return parent::query($sqlStatement, $bindParams, $bindTypes);
    }

    private function handle93syntax($sqlStatement)
    {
        $specials = join('|', ['SUB_QUERY', 'PG_JSON_PATH']);
        $pattern = "/($specials)[\\s]*\\([\\s]*\\'(.*)\\'[\\s]*\\)/";

        $sqlStatement = preg_replace_callback(
            $pattern,
            function(array $matches){
                $content = str_replace("''", "'", $matches[2]);
                return $content;
            },
            $sqlStatement
        );

        return $sqlStatement;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For now you can use built-in postgres function [json_extract_path_text](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE):

```
UserModel::query()->where("json_extract_path_text(data, 'email') = :email:");
```

Answer (score 0):

See if there's an underlying function implementing the `->>` operator, and use that instead. You can look up `pg_operator` for the `oprname` of `->>` ; there you'll see the `oprcode` identifying the underlying function. There may be multiple entries for different combinations of data types, so you'll have to select the correct one. You can join `oprleft` and `oprright` on `pg_type` to get type names if you need to.

That'll give you a temporary workaround. A better approach would be to avoid trying to parse SQL in your framework, or fixing its parser to deal with complex operators.

Comment: Phalcon is written in C and all queries are internally translated to a special language called PHQL which itself is implemented using lemon. I dug through the source code, and there is no indication that the `->>` notation could be supported by qurrent PHQL implementation. I'll try to [recompile the PHQL module](http://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/1446/how-can-i-extend-the-phql-syntax-is-parser-lemon-outdated-) when I find some spare time.

Answer (score 0):

As per Craig answer, You can execute this query on Postgres to find the operator you are looking for and the equivalent oprcode to use in your query:
For example:
`SELECT oprcode FROM pg_operator WHERE oprname = '->>';`

You will get many results, use the appropriate one.

Thanks,